# Cannot configure tests in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

When running the command "Python: Configure Tests" in Visual Studio Code I get following error:

```
command "python.configure tests" not found
```

I uninstalled Python extension for vscode and tried to reinstall it but I get this error now:

```
Activating extension 'ms-python.python' failed: Expected a string, got undefined.
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out I'd the following setting in my settings.json:

```
python.jediEnabled: true
```

After removing this setting, Python extension was installed successfully. After this, the command `python.configure tests` became available.

I would also recommend removing Anaconda Extension Pack as this might interfere with Python extension (though I'm not sure).

Comment: The Anaconda extension pack doesn't affect the Python extension; it simply installs it plus the Red Hat YAML extension. And the `"python.jediEnabled"` setting won't affect the extension as that's a legit setting for the extension. The error you got unfortunately occurs when installation fails of the extension.

Comment: Thanks, That's good insight but in my case removing `python.jediEnabled` setting fixed the issue. This and removing Anaconda Extension pack was the only two things I did. Hope there is a better error indicating which extension is causing error and due to what setting.

Comment: Mine was `python.jediEnabled: false` still just removing that one line helped. Thanks!